# Entity Framework: Why is a property of type array of objects not persisted to DB?

Tags: entity-framework, orm

I have two entities where one has a one to many relationship to the other. Example:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Answer[] Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public int Id {get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Using EF6 Code First I've setup this simple DbContext:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

What I end up with in the DB are two similarly structured tables (int PK column and varchar column) and no representation of the "one Question has many Answers" relationship that I intended with the Question.Answers property.

Why doesn't EF Code First map the relationship and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entity Framework doesn't support mapping navigation properties of bare Array types. The property has to be of Type that implements the `ICollection<T>` interface in order to be mapped.

Try to change your code as follows:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

And when initializing `Answers`, set it to a `HashSet` or `List`:

```
this.Answers = new List<Answer>();
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I don't have the option of replacing the array with an ICollection? Is there any sort of workaround I could setup?

Comment: You could create a (private) backing field that will be mapped by EF, and expose it through your current `Answer[] Answers` property. Let me know if you want me to add the code to the answer.

Comment: Many thanks haim770. Please do add the code to the answer for future reference.

Comment: After second thought, I don't think it's a good idea because you'll have no way to add/remove from the (mapped) answers collection since the public `Answers` property is effectively merely a detached copy of the backing field (using `ToArray()` method), any attempt to manipulate it will not be tracked by EF and will only confuse consumers.