# Migration fails when navigationproperty is an Array instead of a list in C# - Entity Framework Standard

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration

i'm trying to add a migration, but as the title says, it fails because my navigation property is an array instead of a list.

I've tried to change it to list and it works fine, but i dont want a list. I really need it to be an array. any ideas?

the follwing is a example of my class:

```
class Person {
  string Name;
  int Age;
  Address[] Addresses;
}
```

this is the error throwed by ef:

The navigation property 'Addresses' is not a declared property on type 'Person'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from the model and that it is a valid navigation property.

this is how i mapped the relationship:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
              .HasMany(x => x.Addresses)
              .WithOptional()
              .Map(y =>
              {
                  y.MapKey("AddressId");
              }
            );
```

Remenber, as i said before, if i chagne the type of the addresses to a List it works fine. But thats not what i want.

thx in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Framework: Why is a property of type array of objects not persisted to DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646461/entity-framework-why-is-a-property-of-type-array-of-objects-not-persisted-to-db)

Comment: Arrays are not supported. Your property needs to implement `ICollection<T>`

Comment: ok, so as a workaround i'll have too create a list to save it in db, and another variable to hold the array. not the best of the worlds, but i cannot replace my arrays, I gave you only an example, but my implementation is huge. Thx anyway @nilsK

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be adapting legacy code which used Arrays for its domain over to EF and want those legacy classes to become entities or be swapped out by entities.

EF doesn't support arrays as navigation properties. The recommended navigation property type is `ICollection<T>` however, `ICollection<T>` won't support things like an Indexer. (`[]`)

One option is to declare the collections as `IList<T>` which does have an indexer so legacy code using `[]` syntax can still reach elements. A caveat of using `IList<T>` over `ICollection<T>` is that you must avoid using the Indexer within Linq expressions. For example, the following statement will compile, but EF will throw an exception:

```
var firstSecondOrder = context.Customers
    .Where(x => x.Orders.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => x.Orders[1])  // <-- Indexer not allowed here.
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I suspect based on your comment "I really need it to be an array." that this may still not be sufficient, though it would help if you elaborate exactly *why* you feel it must be an array? The only potentially breaking code I can think of between an `IList<T>` and `T[]` would be any code that sets the collection to a new value. I.e.:

```
customer.Orders = new Order[0];
```

... or possibly a significant amount of code invested in Array-specific methods or extension methods. (Extension methods can easily have `IList<T>` flavours added) Navigation collection properties should never be re-initialized, whether `ICollection<T>` or arrays.

Comment: hey Steve, thank you for your answer. In fact I wanted to check if there is any chance of creating that relationship using arrays, but as u said, thats not supported. So I have to create some workarounds on my project. Its not perfect but that's what we got. cya